# SOAP service with microstrategy

Tags: soap, xquery, ws-security, microstrategy

I want to consume a SOAP service with microstrategy. For that I need to prepare a Xquery document to consume the web webservice.

I am tryeing to create a New Simple Xquery using the Xquery editor that microstrategy provides (XEG)

[Image sample of the wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0ws7.png)

I already have been able to connect a basic service. The problem I have here is that I need to a add a UsernameToken like this one in the header to pass throught an API Gateway.

```
<wsse:Security
  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1D1B69223E465C5FF516989396012348">
    <wsse:Username>User1</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password
      Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">
      nxrzIqhN9oZm5ObKRN7naw9K5xE=</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce
      EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
      +d6lI3xbW0F/FW5MqMYINA==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2023-11-02T15:40:01.234Z</wsu:Created>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Comment: It looks like you have already added the credentials to the SOAP Header. What's the problem? Are they dynamic?